# Get Version hierarchy using Web Service API

Tags: jira, greenhopper

The Greenhopper in Jira allows hierarchy of versions(Parent- child relationships between versions). [Setting up Version Hierarchy](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Setting+Up+a+Version+Hierarchy).

Does Jira or Greenhopper expose a web service Interface to get this hierarchy information?
It seems that it is possible to get this information from the Jira database as shown [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GHKB/Locate+Version+Hierarchy+in+JIRA+Database).

However, any pointers if any web service API is available for retrieving the hierarchy information.

Answer (score 0):

That information isn't available through the APIs (and neither is the Version description) :(